# A simple example of Lindelöf space.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, lindelof-spaces

Somebody can to give me a simple example of Lindelöf space?

Note. Lindelöf space is a topological space in which every open cover has a countable subcover.

Comment: The reals are Lindelof.  In fact any second countable space is Lindelof.

Comment: I guess you want an example in which the subcovers are countable but not finite, do you? You should put that in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural numbers with the discrete topology.

Given an open cover, $U_i$ let $U_n$ be some open set such that $n\in U_n$, then $\{U_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable subcover.

---

Although simpler example, perhaps, would be any compact set. I still think that you may benefit from a non-compact example.